# Difference in NetworkImage and Image.network?

Tags: dart, flutter

Are there any difference in both of them?

Whats the disadvantage and which one is easier to use for normal situation?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

> Are there any difference in both of them?

Yes. They are different.

- [NetworkImage](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/painting/NetworkImage-class.html) class creates an object the provides an image from the `src` URL passed to it. It is not a widget and does not output an image to the screen.
- [Image.network](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Image/Image.network.html) creates a widget that displays an image on the screen. It is just a named constructor on the [Image](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Image-class.html) class(a stateful widget). It sets the `image` property using the `NetworkImage` . This `image` property is used finally to display the image.

  ```
  class Image extends StatefulWidget{
    Image(...){}; //default Constructor


    //the argument src is passed to the NetworkImage and assinged to the image property
    Image.network(String src, {...}) : image = NetworkImage(src, ...);


    final ImageProvider image;

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context){
      display the image
      return RawImage(image: image,
        ...
      );
    }
  }
  ```

> Whats the disadvantage and which one is easier to use for normal situation?

There is no disadvantage. You should use the one the suits the need. For example consider:

1. [CircleAvatar](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/CircleAvatar-class.html) widget that displays acircle that represents a user takes `backgroundImage`. It requires an ImageProvider. So you pass `NetworkImage(http://image.com)`
2. [FadeInImage](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FadeInImage-class.html) that displays a placeholder while the original image is loading also takes a `ImageProvider` for its `image` property. So you can provide it `NetworkImage(http://image.com)`.

If you just want to display the image as a widget on screen use `Image.network` and use `NetworkImage` wherever an `ImageProvider` is expected.

Comment: The one confusion I have in the docs for CircleAvatar is "If foregroundImage fails then backgroundImage is used." This, to me, implies that `foregroundImage` should be preferred as the key. But the constructor does first list the `backgroundImage` as the first ImageProvider type.

Comment: I am using photo_view package available at https://pub.dev/packages/photo_view. My code is as: PhotoView(
                  imageProvider: NetworkImage(
                    widget.photoPath.toString(),
                  ),),  Kindly suggest how can I use placeholder image until network image is loaded. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Another difference I can see is, with `Image.network` you can use the `loadingBuilder` method to show the image loading progress which is useful to users in some situations.