# I get an error when I try to use the image network in Flutter instead of the image entity image What is the solution?

Tags: flutter

I get an error when I want to use image network instead of asset image. Can you find a solution?I get an error when I try to use the image network in Flutter instead of the image entity image What is the solution?

```
       new GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                         _fraURL();
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.transparent,
                        image: new DecorationImage(
                     -----> image: AssetImage(
                              "res/c3.jpg"),<----
                          fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),



    new GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                     _fraURL();
                },
                child: Container(
                  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.transparent,
                    image: new DecorationImage(
                      image: new Image.network(
            'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/book-7a285.appspot.com/o/ic_launcher.png?alt=media&token=605f6d54-7098-487c-ae4c-f70ae4476670'),
                      fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),


     image: new Image.network(
                'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/book-7a285.appspot.com/o/ic_launcher.png?alt=media&token=605f6d54-7098-487c-ae4c-f70ae4476670')        

 <-----i can't run it
```

Comment: Use NetworkImage instead of Image.network: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52243595/1418938

Comment: yes, but the image network is failing, do you think I'm writing the code wrong?