# Having trouble adding ImageNetwork to streambuilder using snapshot.data

Tags: flutter, dart

Im having trouble adding NetworkImage to container using streambuilder to fetch image from firestore. "name" works great but the image is not showing up.

```
body:   Container(
          child: StreamBuilder(
    stream: Firestore.instance.collection('Agents').snapshots(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData) return Text('Loading');
      return Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(snapshot.data.documents[0]['name']),
          NetworkImage(snapshot.data.documents[0]['image']),



        ],
      );
    },

  ),

        ),
```

Comment: Do you have a field called image

Comment: Use print to see what it gives you

Answer (score 0):

try `Image.network()` instead.

see the difference between `Image.network()` and `NetworkImage()` here: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52242995/difference-in-networkimage-and-image-network)